# Android: converting String to int

Tags: android, string, int

I'm simply trying to convert a string that is generated from a barcode scanner to an int so that I can manipulate it by taking getting the remainder to generate a set number of integers.  So far I have tried:

```
int myNum = 0;

try {
    myNum = Integer.parseInt(myString.getText().toString());
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {

}
```

and

```
Integer.valueOf(mystr);
```

and

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(string);
```

The first one gives me the error :The method getText() is undefined for the type String
while the last two don't have any compile errors but the app crashes immediately when those are called.  I thought it had to do with my barcode scanning intent method but I put it into the OnCreate and still got the error.

Comment: Can you print out the value of `myString`? Are you sure that it contains an integer (only digits, not larger than `2^31`)? Are you getting any exceptions when the app crashes?

Comment: Hey, do you know how to convert String to Cursor? I saw [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917935/adding-rows-into-cursor-manually) but I couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 48):

Change

```
try {
    myNum = Integer.parseInt(myString.getText().toString());
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
```

to

```
try {
    myNum = Integer.parseInt(myString);
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
```

Answer (score 9):

It's already a string? Remove the getText() call.

```
int myNum = 0;

try {
    myNum = Integer.parseInt(myString);
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
  // Handle parse error.
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You just need to write the line of code to convert your string to int.

```
 int convertedVal = Integer.parseInt(YOUR STR);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Use regular expression:**

```
int i=Integer.parseInt("hello123".replaceAll("[\\D]",""));
int j=Integer.parseInt("123hello".replaceAll("[\\D]",""));
int k=Integer.parseInt("1h2el3lo".replaceAll("[\\D]",""));
```

**output:**

```
i=123;
j=123;
k=123;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expression:

```
String s="your1string2contain3with4number";
int i=Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""))
```

output: i=1234;

If you need first number combination then you should try below code:

```
String s="abc123xyz456";
int i=((Number)NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(s)).intValue()
```

output: i=123;

Comment: I used both method but second is working but its changing the value completly ! String valu "4307764028" => 12796732

Answer (score 1):

barcode often consist of large number so i think your app crashes because of the size of the string that you are trying to convert to `int`. you can use `BigInteger`

```
BigInteger reallyBig = new BigInteger(myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not convert to string if your integer value is zero or starts with zero (in which case 1st zero will be neglected).
Try change.

```
int NUM=null;
```

Comment: int is not an object, so can not be null!

Comment: well if that is the case then i suppose Microsoft only enabled it in my visualstudio.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String t1 = name.getText().toString();
Integer t2 = Integer.parseInt(mynum.getText().toString());

boolean ins = myDB.adddata(t1,t2);

public boolean adddata(String name, Integer price)
```

Comment: this way is how you insert mynum to database
the boolean part is how you insert data in your db then create an if-else condition to check if data has been inserted, 

take note make sure that your add data has the right parameters in your databasehandler

Answer (score -1):

// Convert String to Integer

```
// String s = "fred";  // use this if you want to test the exception below


String s = "100"; 
try
{
  // the String to int conversion happens here
  int i = Integer.parseInt(s.trim());

  // print out the value after the conversion
  System.out.println("int i = " + i);
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
{
  System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
}
```