# How to increase textView interger value and pass it to variable if textView also contains text?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
 diceBidSelect1.setOnClickListener {
            diceBidImage1.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_1)
```

If there is only integer in textView, I do this:

```
  val value = Integer.parseInt(diceBidSelectText1.text.toString()) + 1
        diceBidSelectText1.text = Integer.toString(value)
```

But how to increment if textView includes text, for example "1x".
I also would like to know how to pass integer to a variable.

Comment: I didn't quite catch your question... do you need to increment the number like `1x`,`2x`,`3x`

Comment: Yes. You're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to merge a digit with a character like in case x, you can concatenate digit and text like this in kotlin, val cant be changed once set change it to var

```
var value = "${Integer.parseInt(diceBidSelectText1.text.toString()) + 1}x"
        diceBidSelectText1.text = value
```

Comment: Thanks, but something is wrong with it. I get `Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)` on `$` and the middle text is greyed out.

Comment: Thanks, now I get `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1x"`

Comment: Store this Integer.parseInt(diceBidSelectText1.text.toString())  in new integer and debug this line to check if you really getting integer value from edit text then add increment to your integer

Comment: I think the problem is that textView contains not only integer but also "x"

Comment: yes you should check if your edit text only return integer or not, if it return integer then my answer is valid

Comment: My question was "if textView also contains text?". But I'm very grateful for your effort.

Comment: brother then you should check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21488717/5088314